# 'Pin-art' effect in After effects

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I'm looking for a way to create a 'Pin art toy' effect in after effects. Basically a load of extruded hexagons that can be pushed up and down by a shape behind them.

Would be great if this could be done with 3d shapes using the cinema 4d render, or if not, isometric style 2d would also work.

My thinking would be for each hexagon to look at the colour that is below it and map the z position so that white = 100% raised, black = 0% etc.

Thanks for any input

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your approach sounds like it would work.